# Django convert raw SQL ordering to QuerySet API

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I'm trying to perform natural ordering on CharField for model (here simplified version):

```
class House(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=32)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.number)

>>> House.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<House: 2>, <House: 1>, <House: 4>, <House: 3>, <House: 1b>, <House: 2b>, <House: 1c>, <House: 13c>, <House: 10>, <House: 2e>, <House: 3ab>]>
```

I have managed to order it by raw SQL query:

```
House.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM entry_house ORDER BY(substring(number, '^[0-9]+'))::int, substring(number, '[0-9].*$')")
```

But I need to get QuerySet object not RawQuerySet (for our current pagination implementation). Iterating over all raw queryset is not an option because of huge amount of data.

How can I convert result of RawQuerySet to QuerySet or even better, how to convert this raw SQL query to Django QuerySet API?

Comment: Have you tried  `House.objects.all().order_by(column_name)` instead of raw sql query ?

Comment: I need to do a natural sort on charfield. I need objects ordered like this (1, 1b, 1c, 2, 2b, 3, 4, ... 10, 11). And normal order_by orders it like (1, 10, 11, 2...)

Comment: If you insist on using alnum codes, you can lpad them with zeros to get a natural sort (ie : "001", "001b", "010", "011b", "003" etc). This can be done on `model.save()`, and will yield better perfs than using `substring` with regexps.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I guess this would work but I'd prefer to achive this without modifying data or adding another field with normalized code.

Comment: Since you're using Postgresql, consider creating an immutable user defined function that produces a `(number, label)` tuple (or such) from your `number` column and follow @schwobaseggl's advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your postgres backend, you can do something like the following, using the [`regexp_replace`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html) function:

```
from django.db.models import Func, F, Value, IntegerField
from django.db.models.functions import  Cast

House.objects.all()\
    .annotate(inumber=Cast(
         Func(F('number'),    # take number
              Value('[^\d]'), # pattern to replace: non-digits
              Value(''),      # replacement
              Value('g'),     # global flag; replace all occurrences
              function='regexp_replace'), 
         IntegerField()))\    # output type of cast
    .order_by('inumber', 'number')  # fallback to non-digit portion
```

The `Func` removes non-digits from `number` ([Django database functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/database-functions/)). The annotation casts the result to an integer. There might be even better functions available, but for the above data, this should work.

Comment: This work really good for most cases. Unfortunately our main database has some houses with number actually not containg any integers or just empty string (sorry I wasn't aware of this before) and this code crashes with exception: django.db.utils.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: ""
Is there some workaround for this?

Comment: You can look at [`Case`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case), but at some point, this query will just be a Frankenstein monster :), where some denormalisation with an extra order field would be appropriate. What is the expected order for those houses anyway?

Comment: I guess they should appear at the end or begining, doesn't really matter that much. I wanted to avoid modyfing models for this but it might just be the most sensible option :)